# React axios api call returns "net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED 200" error in chrome devtools

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, google-chrome-devtools

I am facing a strange error while react axios is calling an api in my application. In one of my screens in react application I am calling an api using axios, check the below code:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get('https://617eabfe2ff7e600174bd8a8.mockapi.io/crud')
    .then((getData) => {
        setApiData(getData.data);
    })
}, [])
```

Everything works fine until I browse the application normally in browser. But when I open the chrome devtools and refresh the page I am getting the below error:

[image]

The error seems an internet error so I checked my internet thoroughly and it is working fine. If I close the devtools window and refresh the page then the error is disappearing and the api returns the data (working fine).

After doing some testing my observation is axios API call is not working when my devtools window (I am using chrome browser) is opened. Mates help me in understanding the axios api call behavior.

Comment: Thanks mate. It worked. From past one week I am searching here and there. Finally you saved my time.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Happy coding mate.